# Save data from form

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I want to save the data that I get from my form (html).
I have same fileds in my form and I want to send them from html page to node.js page and from there to mongoDB (mlab) database.
In my node page I use angular to save the data that I gets form user.
I'm using ng-controller to connect to js page, and using ng-model to hold the data that I get in input label.
My problem is that I cant save the data in mongoDB?

Thanks,

html:

```
 <body ng-controller="addController">
        <h1 class="text-center">Add Activity</h1>
        <form class="form-group" ng-submit="createActivity()">
          <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-10">
          <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Title:</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Title" ng-model="title"></input>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Age:</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" type="number" placeholder="Age" ng-model="age" min="0" max="16"></input>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Description:</label>
             <textarea class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" type="text" placeholder="Description" ng-model="description"></textarea>
             <br>
             </div>
             <div class="col-sm-10">
             <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Themes:</label>
              <input type="radio" name="themes" value="frozen" ng-model="theme">frozen &nbsp;
              <input type="radio" name="themes" value="minions" ng-model="theme">minions &nbsp;
              <input type="radio" name="themes" value="heroes" ng-model="theme">heroes
              <input type="radio" name="themes" value="princess" ng-model="theme">princess &nbsp;
              <input type="radio" name="themes" value="piraets" ng-model="theme">piraets &nbsp;
              <input type="radio" name="themes" value="none" ng-model="theme">none 
              <br>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
            <br>
            <input type="file" name="upload" ng-model="image"></input>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
            <br>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="send"></input>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
```

js:

```
var addActivityApp = angular.module('addActivityApp',['$scope','$resource']);
var Activity = $resource('/activities');
var activity = new Activity();

$scope.createActivity=function () {
    var activity = new Activity();
    activity.title = $scope.title;
    activity.age = $scope.age;
    activity.description = $scope.description;
    activity.theme = $scope.theme;
    activity.$save(function (result) {
      $scope.activities.push(result);
      $scope.title = '';
      $scope.age = '';
      $scope.description = '';
      $scope.theme = '';
    });
  }); 



addActivityApp.controller('addController',function($scope) {
    $scope.addController = model;


});
```

Comment: Where is your connection to mongoDB ?

Comment: my connection is from the server said this is my client said.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code. check if you using the same below code on your server side.

```
app.post('yourserverurl', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body) //Here all form data will display
    var InsertData = req.body;

    db.collection('restaurants').insertOne(InsertData,function(err, result) {
    assert.equal(err, null);
    console.log("Inserted a document into the collection.");
    callback();
  });


});
```

if you share the whole code which you have written in server side, so i can simplify it more